# Total Noob Question for Digitizing old copies of copies of copies

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

totally new to the forum and have a totally noob question.  I have a copy of a copy of a copy of a 1969 Corvette Assembly Instruction Manual and am curious as to what it would take to digitize it.  From my limited research, it appears Adobe Illustrator is one tool and Photoshop another but I need to understand what I may be getting myself into as the manual is ~500 pages.

I am not looking for absolute perfection.  My intention is to share this with other Corvette Forum members to help them in the pursuit of their hobby so the goal is to get it into a shape that is useable for a hobbyist.  Some of the members have copies that have been recopied so many times it is difficult to read some of the information.

Can someone give me a high level guesstimate of what it would take to accomplish this?  Attached is a sample page.

Thanks all and Happy Easter

Comment: …or you could just see if anyone else has already done it & put it online for all to see - http://www.corvette-restoration.com/wp-content/uploads/technical_papers/69_Corvette_Assembly_Manual.pdf

Comment: Credit here :http://www.forum.corvette-restoration.com/viewtopic.php?t=2486 If I were you, I'd be looking to buy Brookster a beer, or three.

Comment: I don't have a 'Vette but I do have a classic car.. I've found the hard copy manuals invaluable compared to anything digital. Honestly, I find the $53 to buy the assembly and shop manuals ([here](https://www.corvettecentral.com/c3-68-82/books/assembly-shop-manual/)) to be essentially *nothing* in terms of price. And it's *really* hard to thumb through a PDF or swipe a digital screen while working on the car. But.. maybe that's me.

Comment: @Scott When I was younger, I'd buy the Haynes for every car I owned. These days I either read it off the iPad or print it out - can get it as oily as you like & just bin it afterwards. Print a fresh copy if you need; original is safe.

Comment: Yeah. I thought of that as well @Tetsujin .. but... cost of printer ink will *quickly* surpass the cost of the manuals. :) It's easier to wipe your hands first for me :) And the grease.. that's part of the charm :)

Comment: @Scott - *"And the grease.. that's part of the charm :)"* I once used that argument with an American friend of mine when I first took him for British fish & chips. He wasn't convinced ;))

Comment: He was wrong `:)` (and I'm 'merican)